# Simple array to CSV in ruby with new line added

Tags: ruby, csv

I have the following script:

```
require 'CSV'

colors = ["red", "blue", "green"]

CSV.open("valid_urls.csv", "w") do |csv|
    csv << colors
end
```

With this code, the contents of my CSV looks like this:

`red,blue,green`

However, what I want is this:

```
red
blue
green
```

I tried doing something like `colors = ["red", "blue", "green"].join "\n"` but I get a `undefined method`collect'` error.

Comment: What do you mean by "the contents of my CSV looks like"? I don't see any code where you output anything so what object are you examining and where are you examining it?

Comment: `require 'CSV'` 85:in `require': cannot load such file -- CSV (LoadError)
Did you mean?  csv

Comment: You needn't use a CSV method: `IO.write("valid_urls.csv", colors.join("\n"))`. See [IO::write](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-write).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you append an flat array to a csv, it makes a single row. It looks like you want 3 rows? If so, then:

```rb
require 'CSV'

colors = ["red", "blue", "green"]

CSV.open("valid_urls.csv", "w") do |csv|
    colors.each do |color|
      csv << [color]
    color
end
```

does that give you what you're looking for?

Comment: This works. Thank you!  the brackets around color when adding it to the csv object is what was throwing me off.